# Swift - How to decode flat json to nested structure?

Tags: ios, swift, decoding

Let's say I have the following JSON which I would like to decode to this a particular structure. How do I do this

JSON:

```
{
 "fullName": "Federico Zanetello",
 "id": 123456,
 "twitter": "http://twitter.com/zntfdr",
 "results": ["mate","bate"]
}
```

Decoded Struct

```
struct Response {
    let data: UserData,
    let results: [String]
}
```

The `UserData` struct

```
Struct UserData {
   let fullName: String,
   let id: Int,
   let twitter: String
}
```

I did my research and couldn't find a valid solution. Here is the code I wrote so far

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
    let fullName: String
    let id: Int
    let twitter: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fullName
        case id
        case twitter
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.fullName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fullName)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.twitter = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .twitter)
    }
}

struct Respone: Decodable{
    let data: UserData
    let results: [String]
}

let json = """
{
 "fullName": "Federico Zanetello",
 "id": 123456,
 "twitter": "http://twitter.com/zntfdr",
 "results": ["mate","bate"]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)! // our data in native (JSON) format
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(MetaData.self, from: json) // Decoding our data
print(myStruct)
```

I'm getting KeynotFound error because `data` key is not present in the JSON. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
    let fullName: String
    let id: Int
    let twitter: String
}

struct Response: Decodable{
    let data: UserData
    let results: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case results
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        results = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .results)
        data = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(UserData.self)
    }
}
```

The trick is to use custom decoding in `Response`, and after decoding the `results` like you do normally, get a `singleValueContainer`. This container will contain all the keys in your JSON, so you can use this container to decode the `UserData`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this struct.. Data is not present as a key in your response

```
// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let fullName: String
    let id: Int
    let twitter: String
    let results: [String]
}
```

Ad decode it like this

```
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: json)
```

Note: you dont need `init()` function for codable if you are not performing anything extra.. And dont need `CodingKeys` if names of your struct elements are same

Here is how you can use `UserData` as separate object with `interface segregation`

```
struct Response: UserData, Codable {
    let fullName: String
    let id: Int
    let twitter: String
    let results: [String]
}

protocol UserData {
    var fullName: String {get}
    var id: Int {get}
    var twitter: String{get}
}

  let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json)

  let userData : UserData = myStruct 

  print(userData.fullName)
```

Comment: I want fullName, id, twitter as part of UserData object and not as individual fields inside User

Comment: How would I use UserData in this case?

Comment: when response get values ... your userData will fill itself with those values ... and you can use that ... i will update answer with example

Comment: @Kiran let me know if you need further assistance =)

Comment: This answer works but the answer by @sweeper is what I am looking for. Thanks for the help